# How to make a program restart infinitely using while loops in C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, dev-c++

I am a beginner at learning C language, I have an assignment asking me to write a program that determines whether the data inputted by user makes sense as triangle sides or not.

If it is, I have to determine the type of the triangle, and if it is not, an output such as "It is not a triangle" should be written.

I have to use a `while` loop for this purpose, and not allowed to use `do while`.

So that's what I've coded. I'm using DevC++ program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    printf("Enter the first side:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the second side:\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Enter the third side:\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    while ((a > 0) && (b > 0) && (c > 0))
    {
        if (((a + b) > c) && ((a + c) > b) && ((b + c) > a))
        {
            if ((a == b) && (b == c))
            {
                printf("That is an EQUILATERAL triangle\n");
                break;
            }
            if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c))
            {
                printf("That is an ISOSCELES triangle\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("That is a SCALENE triangle\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("That is not a TRIANGLE.\n");
            break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now the problems I have are; I am asked to make the program restarts (repeats) itself after each time we have the decision if it is a triangle or not, but I don't know how. This "break" statement that I have written does not work and I think it is not necessary am I right? Also there is this error that comes out when I check my code

```
D:\Homework1.c  [Error] expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Could you help me please?

Edit1: Simply and specifically, the loop should always be repeated unless the input numbers are not 0 or (-). So users will always be able to re-enter values if they are not 0 or negative ( And actually that's the loop main condition)
Edit2: I corrected missing } and ((b + c) > c) errors so thank you all.

Comment: Your task is to make it repeat and you're not allowed to use loops? ... Sigh, another teacher with idiotic tasks. Use goto.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?  There are cases where it makes sense to tag with both languages (where one is asking "compare and contrast" type questions).  This is not one of them.

Comment: I have no idea how a "date" have anything to do with triangle.  Anyway, just get a tutorial or intro book, and look at the section of "Looping"

Comment: @deviantfan: They *are* allowed to use loops:  Just a `while(...) { .... }`, not a `do { ... } while(...);` loop.

Comment: while (true) { /* do whatever thing you want */ }

Comment: but before you move on, the first thing you need to learn is to properly indent your code.  By doing so, you should find out you are missing a closing bracket.

Comment: why do you use a `while` loop if you `break` out of it anyway on the first iteration?

Comment: I have to use while loop who said I am not allowed to use loops?! ,I meant  just integers by saying data..+ I will remove C++ tag.

Comment: The error you get is because you forgot to put a `}` at the very end of your code.

Comment: `(b + c) > c` should be `(b + c) > a`.

Comment: I am understanding somethings now, thank you.. actually I had no time to study C properly because of the other course..so if anyone can make an editing/
correction to my code I will be so thankful :D

Comment: @utdlegend It's not clear when the program should finish, or should it run forever ? Could you edit your question and add an example of input and expected output. As far as I understood the `while (true)` solution in Adrian Shum's comment is what you need.

Comment: Isn't a triangle basically defined by `a+b+c==180`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That applies to corner angles, not side lengths.

Answer (score 1):

here you can go for many ways...

1.Use label,goto

2.Go for functions

3.Avoid break;

4.Alter the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int flag=1;//for handling while loop
    while (flag)
    {
        //call a function to input 
        //call a function to process
        //call a function to output
        //flag = get input to repeat(1) or finish (0)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Dont use while loop for checking >0 condition. It is of no use.
Here you use if-else, so break condition is not required.
Handle <0 condition also.

Comment: I strongly suggest not to give the full code if it is clear this is homework. Just give the outline and let him/her learn.

Comment: Using `true` for variable name is a very bad idea as it's define in `stdbool.h`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, won't repeat next time... But he's beginner, so he'll learn from other code.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a closing brace `}` at the end of your `main` (i.e. after `return 0`).  This might be a reason for your compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a loop, `while` in your case with an endless condition to run. Endless at first but give the ability to the user to be able to terminate the loop.

1. Read your user input at the start of the loop.
2. Process the input, so decide if its a triangle and give an output to the user
3. Ask the user if she/he wants to exit or rerun.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int exit = 0;  // surly you want to exit sometimes
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    while(!exit)
    {
        // Get your input
        printf("Enter the first side:\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Enter the second side:\n");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("Enter the third side:\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);

        // check your input, process data if it is a triangle, give output
        // your code here
        printf("a:%d b:%d c:%d\n", a, b, c); // test code of mine

        // ask if the user wants to rerun
        printf("Exit? Yes(1) No(0):\n");
        scanf("%d",&exit);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP want's.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You mean it should run till a triangle is found? The `exit` variable can be updated by the OP's process. But the principle is the same at the end of the loop someone/something decides if a rerun is needed or not.

Comment: Actually I didn't really understand what the OP wants, it's pretty un clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use while(1) loop, do your inputs and checks in it and after each result use continue